# JQuery - How do I change colour for different toggle buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 different toggle buttons and would like to find out how to change the background color of the 3 toggle buttons using the id (cb1, cb2, cb3) such that each button (when checked) will have a different colour. Let me know how it can be done using jquery?

```
<style>
input#cb1:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input#cb2:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #96F321;
}

input#cb3:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #F32196;
}
</style>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb3">
  <span class="slider"></span>
</label>
```

The below code is the answer.

```
$("input#cb1:checked+.slider").css("background-color","yellow");
$("input#cb2:checked+.slider").css("background-color","brown");
$("input#cb3:checked+.slider").css("background-color","purple");
```

Comment: Replacing `input:checked` with specific id?

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work?  It looks like you've written no JavaScript at all, so you need to start there.  You can respond to the `change` events and set the CSS values of your target elements with jQuery, and any introductory tutorial on jQuery should be able to get you started on that.

Comment: *"Let me know how it can be done using **jquery**"* - why do want/need jquery for this ?  Handled nicely via css.

Comment: I need to use jquery because the colors of the checkbox need to be change every time user click on some buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In your css, you can reference an element by its ID, eg

```
#cb1 + .slider
```

if you want to keep the input part, it's `element#id`, eg `input#cb1`

Updated snippet example:

```css
input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

.slider {
  background-color: black;
}

input#cb1:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input#cb2:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #96F321;
}

input#cb3:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #F32196;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb1">
  <span class="slider">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb2">
  <span class="slider">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</label>

<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" id="cb3">
  <span class="slider">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
</label>
```

Comment: So, what is the question? What are you answering for?

Comment: @freedomn-m Thanks for your answer, it is useful for me but I would like to know how to change each toggle button using the id, let me know if it is possible?